# Topic.count didn't change by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake

I am testing the create method of my topics controller and keep getting this error:

```
"Topic.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 4
  Actual: 3
```

I have tried a bunch of different solutions from changing the number of attributes that I send in the params to changing what the attributes themselves are, but nothing seems to be working.  Any ideas?

Here is my create method:

```
def create
    topic = current_user.topics.create(topic_params)
    if topic.save
      redirect_to topic
      unless current_user.reload.spammer?
        AdminMailer.topic_created(topic).deliver_now
      end
    else
      redirect_to topics_path, flash: 'Failed to save this question. Please try again or contact email@domain.com'
    end
  end
```

Here is my test:

```
test "should create topic" do
    assert_difference 'Topic.count' do 
        post topics_url, params: {topic: {title: 'this is a topic', message_attributes: {text: 'this is the question'}, user_id: @user.id, bound_id: @bound.id}}
    end
    assert_redirected_to topics_url(Topic.last)
  end
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use `save!` so any failures are impossible to ignore due to exceptions being thrown. You can `rescue` these using either an explicit `rescue` block or the `rescue_from` method.

Comment: @tadman I tried replacing topic.save with topic.save! but ran into the same error.  What is `rescue`?

Comment: It would seem that your `post` in the test isn't correct, so no record is actually created. You're using `@user.id` in your params, is `@user` a defined variable?

Comment: @NickEmmons It's part of exception handling in Ruby, so if you're not familiar with it you'll need to visit that section of your reference or introduction material to familiarize yourself with it. A lot of Ruby code will emit exceptions and it often falls on you as the developer to properly catch and respond to these. Any good introductory book, like the [standard reference](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/), will cover this.

Comment: @DanielWestendorf yeah sorry I didn't add the setup to the question.  `@bound` and `@user` are both defined in the setup for the test.  Is the post in the test still incorrect though?